# Center x-axis labels in grouped violin/boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am creating violin plots by groups. I would like to label each group using a Greek letter centered at the middle point of each group of violin plots. **How can I do this?**

So far, I am using `scale_x_discrete`, but I cannot indicate any sort of centering.

```
library(ggplot2)
dat <- matrix(rnorm(100*12),ncol=12)

# Violin plots for columns
mat <- reshape2::melt(data.frame(dat), id.vars = NULL)

mat$variable_grouping <- ifelse(mat$variable %in% c('X1', 'X2', 'X3','X4'), 'g1',
                                ifelse(mat$variable %in% c('X5','X6','X7','X8'), 
                                       'g2', 'g3'))

pp <- ggplot(mat, aes(x = variable, y = value, fill = variable_grouping)) + 
  geom_violin(scale="width",adjust = 1,width = 0.5) + 
  scale_x_discrete(labels = c(expression(theta[1]),"","","",expression(theta[2]),"","","",expression(theta[3])))
pp
```

[image]

In this example, the labels should be at 2.5, 6.5 and 8.5.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: @PoGibas How can I produce labels centered by group, as indicated in the last line, after the reproducible example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A different solution:

```
library(ggplot2)

pp <- ggplot(mat, aes(x = as.numeric(variable), y = value, 
                      group = variable, fill = variable_grouping)) + 
  geom_violin(scale="width", adjust = 1, width = 0.5) + xlab("variable") +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(2.5, 6.5, 10.5), 
              labels = c(expression(theta[1]),expression(theta[2]),expression(theta[3])))
pp
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect solution! PS: it only works if `variable` is factor.

Answer (score 2):

You can **manually** change horizontal position of x-axis labels in `theme`.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mat, aes(variable, value, fill = variable_grouping)) + 
    geom_violin(scale = "width", adjust = 1, width = 0.5) +
    scale_x_discrete(labels = c(expression(theta[1]), "", "", "",
                                expression(theta[2]), "", "", "",
                                expression(theta[3]))) +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust = -8),
          axis.ticks.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

PS: I also removed x-axis ticks.

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I am looking for. However, for some reason, when I run the code, I do not get the centered labels as in your pic. Do you know why?

Comment: You have to center them manually (change `hjust = -8` to whatever works with your device dimensions).

Comment: It is a bit fiddly and sensitive, but I will play with it. Many thanks.